# Trying to run some apps from cmd doesn't start them properly

Tags: windows-10, ssh, cmd.exe

Noob here.
I was playing around with ssh and was trying to run some commands (start some apps) on my ssh server (win10). Running anydesk.exe for example, actually opens the program and I can connect. Playing an mp3 also works. But if I try to start firefox it starts in the background and doesn't open the browser in the foreground.I can see it as a process in the task manager but that's it.
Also Firefox (or even internet explorer) doesn't start "properly" even if I try from cmd on the win10 machine (physically or with anydesk). I also tried to open signal messenger and this one tried to start in dos mode and crashed of course. So my question is, why some apps start in the gui...some in the background and some in dos? And how do I get them to start in gui if I want to?

Answer (score 0):

*This answer if Mozilla apps specific. However other apps may have similar structure, given how long running and influential Mozilla has been over the last 25 years.*

Every Firefox window is a child of a single process, which is tied to a user profile(for data management i.e. history, bookmarks, saved form data, cache etc.). When Firefox gets executed, it checks whether a running instance of Firefox exists, and passes the request to the running instance instead of starting up a new instance.

To alter this behaviour, Firefox needs to be started as follows:

```
firefox -no-remote
```

However, this can cause issues with the default profile data, as now there are 2 processes reading and writing to the same profile data. This can be fixed by invoking the profile manager with

```
firefox -no-remote -ProfileManager
```

There are other profile management options too, which are listed in the [Firefox documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions#-new-instance).

*Note: The proper option for a new instance is actually `-new-instance`, but the Firefox wiki mentions that there are/were issues with it working in MSWin builds.*